# VS2008 Possible to direct output to VS output window for a console application rather than cmd.exe?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

i know its possible for a windows application, but is it possible to re-direct the output of a console app to the internal output window for VS2008?

Answer (score 1):

Use `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine()`